# Should I specify Prior or Cost matrix with Tree Bagger in Matlab

Tags: classification, matlab, random-forest, unbalanced-classes

I'm trying to create Random Forests in Matlab and there are more observations in some classes than there are in others. Do I need to specify this as a cost matrix or as a prior probability or will Matlab figure this out automatically and the fact the data is skewed won't matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a large skew in the class distribution, I recommend training TreeBagger without passing prior or cost. If you have 2 classes, plot the ROC curve using the perfcurve function. Find the optimal operating point or any optimal (by your definition) point based on the values of FPR and TPR. If you have three or more classes, set up a misclassification cost matrix to account for class imbalance. Then classify an observation into the class with minimal expected cost. To compute the expected cost, obtain an N-by-K matrix P of posterior probabilities from TreeBagger.predict (2nd output) for N observations and K classes. Form a K-by-K cost matrix C, where C(i,j) is the cost of classifying an observation of class i to class j. Then find the index for the class with minimal cost using

[~,cls] = min(P*C,2);

and get the actual class value from bagger.ClassNames(cls).

You could play with 'prior' and 'cost' parameters of TreeBagger to make the *training process* more sensitive to observations of one class. As I said, this would only prove useful if the imbalance is large.

Comment: Thanks for geting back to me. What would be considered large? The break down of data is as follows 

23.19%
13.45%
4.60%
8.58%
10.92%
13.58%
11.48%
4.44%
9.76%